# Get link href value from within div/container and navigate to it

Tags: jquery, html, hyperlink, clickable

I'm basically creating a clickable container, which is a list element.  The list element has an anchor tag within it that is invisible.  When the list element is clicked, Jquery is supposed to pull the href value from the anchor tag within the list element, store that href value in a variable, and then use the variable to navigate to the link.  The "clicking the list element" part works pretty well, but the href value for the link within the list value always comes up as undefined. Help? Here's my code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dated-listing>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="no-display" style="visibility:hidden" href="http://www.google.com"></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.dated-listing ul li').click(function(){
    var x = $('a.no-display', this).attr('href');
    window.location.href = x;
});
```

Comment: Its hidden element ,so its undefined

Comment: D'oh!  How stupid of me.  Of course visibility:hidden means the link won't show up at all and that Jquery won't find it.  I should have viewed the source code while the page was up.  Once I changed the link's style to opacity:0, I got the desired effect and the li element navigated to the page. The accidental omission of the closing quote marks happened because I literally hand-typed the code into stackoverflow instead of copying it, but the actual code in my page isn't missing the closing quotes.  Thanks so much!

Comment: lol... `style="visibility:hidden"` is just okay... your eyes is not seeing the element, but jQuery does...

Comment: Forget any comments about hidden elements being invisible to jQuery. That is simply not true. Aside from forgetting a closing `"` on the first div your code is just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/9WtW4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use data-url attribute instead of adding anchor tag which is hidden.

do like this to acheive it:

```
<div class="dated-listing">
    <ul class="test">
        <li data-url="http://www.google.com">dfdsf</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('.dated-listing').on('click','li',function(){

    alert($(this).data('url'))
    window.location.href = $(this).data('url');
});

    });
```

[Here is **Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/p6FA6/)

Comment: While this works as an alternative, the original code had nothing wrong with it *aside from a typo* (missing `"` on the div).

Answer (score 1):

Use following

```
<body>
  <div class="dated-listing">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a class="no-display" style="visibility:hidden" href="http://www.google.com">hi</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $('.dated-listing ul li').click(function(){
            var x = $('a.no-display', this).attr('href');
            window.location.href = x;
            alert(x);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: You forgot Quotes to close "

Comment: +1: This is the correct answer. Aside from a simple typo (which invalidated the HTML) the original code was perfectly fine as-is.